# "case statement does not cover all choices. 'others' clause is needed" with std_logic_vector, but I thought all states are defined

Tags: vhdl

```
signal next_state, current_state: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := "000";
begin
myLogic: process(start, reset, current_state)
begin

case current_state is

    when "000" => --code
    --some if statement
        if start = '1' then
            next_state <= "001";
        end if;
    when "001" => 
        --setting signals
    when "010" =>
        --setting signals
    when "011" =>
        --setting signals

    when "100" =>
        --setting signals
    when "101" =>
        --setting signals
    when "110" =>
        --setting signals
    when "111" =>
        --setting stuff
        end case;
        if reset= '1' then 
            current_state <= "000";
        end if;
end process myLogic;
```

The code I posted above has a state defined by a 3 bit logic vector. But the error I get is that not all cases are covered. When I put a `case others` statement, my code always goes into `others` case.

Comment: No all element values of your std_logic_vector are covered. The element type std_ulogic has nine values, you're only covering two. Add a an others choice even it there is no sequence of statements (or a null statement). Metavalues aren't involved in synthesis. (You could always use bit and bit_vector).

Comment: Provide a [mcve] which would demonstrate how it went there and why it matters, providing enough information for suggesting a corrective action.

Comment: The other issue I was having was that if a variable has a chance to get updated multiple times in a process, the bit might be an X rather than the most recent value. So that is why it was always going into others. @snus74 is correct in his explanation of the others statement.

Comment: You do not show enough of your code.   That said, I see two additional issues.   First, if you do not give next_state a default value before the case statement, then it needs to get a value in every branch - ie:  you need an else to your if statement that assigns to next_state.    Second, your reset is typically coded in the same process that has the state register (flip-flop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cover all possible cases. Logic signals can have *any* value in this list: 'U', 'X', '0', ' 1', 'Z', 'W', 'L', 'H'.
Since in your case all values different from  '0' and '1' are irrelevant, you should add a default case in your switch (in case something wrong happens, and the condition signal has a different value than expected for example)

```
when others =>
```